# HTML5 Local Storage Detecting when data saved

Tags: html, local-storage

I am making little ToDo List using HTML5 local storage. 
I want to show user a tiny notice that says 'SAVED!',
when finished saving data in their local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('todoList', data to save);
```

I dont know if its right way but can i just simply put whatever after `setItem` method?
something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('todoList', data to save); 
alert('saved!');
```

any help please.

Comment: have a read through: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html, it will explain how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can. Here is an example of the code I used in a To-do app just like you:

```
try {
    localStorage.setItem("memo_list", JSON.stringify(list));
    alert('The memo is successfully saved.');
} catch (e) {
    alert('Error saving to storage.');
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is very helpfull and fully working for me as well.